# Braintree split payment paypal

Tags: paypal, payment, braintree

I need to verify that is there is any option to split payment to two different account with paypal in braintree like if customer pay it will send to two different merchant accounts

Comment: Welcome to [so]! At this site you are expected to try to **write the code yourself**. After **[doing more research](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592)** if you have a problem you can **post what you've tried** with a **clear explanation of what isn't working** and providing a [**Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example**](//stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I suggest reading [ask] a good question and [the perfect question](http://codeblog.jonskeet.uk/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question/). Also, be sure to take the [tour] and read **[this](//meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/347937/)**.

Answer (score 1):

This definitely possible through Braintree. Please find the document below which talk about splitting payments

https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/braintree-marketplace/overview?_ga=1.210599248.495264385.1483935796

However, this feature is only available in certain countries. please check about the availability of the feature.

You can achieve this by using PayPal Parallel Payments, which is available in most countries where PayPal is supported.